# how to strip out the time portion from a datetime string

Tags: informatica-powercenter

how to strip out the time portion from a datetime string in Informatica. I can't use GEt_DATE_PART function since the input value is a string value.

Ex. 2019-08-01 14:30:00

I want to strip out the hour, minute and second portions of the string and store them in separate variables.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating two ports, like:

> SUBSTRING(in_date, 1, 10)
>
> SUBSTRING(in_date, 12, 19)

Comment: Thanks, yes I tried the substr function earlier before posting the question. But it did not work for the hour/min/sec section.

Answer (score 0):

You should create 3 variables

```
1. hour = substring(date_in,12,14)
2. minute=substring(date_in,15,17)
3. seconds = substring(date_in,19,21)
```

adjust the length to your preferences depending on the space in the value

Comment: Yes I tried the substr function earlier and that did not work. Its pulling only the date part correctly and giving zeros for the time values. Later it worked after I used the GET_DATE_PART function (after converting the input string to date) for the time values.